# Compiling artoolkitx-calibration for iOS: C-linkage specified, but returns user-defined type 'cv::Size' which is incompatible with C

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, opencv, artoolkit

I'd like to run the [ARToolKitX Calibration app](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration) on iOS. Unfortunately, the app isn't available in the App Store, so I assume I'd have to compile it myself. Luckily, I have an active Apple Developer account...

So I got the source code from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration
cd artoolkitx-calibration
```

Then I downloaded the ARToolKitX iOS library from https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/releases/download and I followed the steps in the iOS section of the [`build.sh`](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration/blob/master/build.sh) script to link this SDK to the Xcode project.

I opened the project with Xcode 9.3 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

I downloaded the `opencv2.framework` library from SourceForge and linked it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/

Xcode reported an issue in [line 61 of `prefs.hpp`](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration/blob/master/prefs.hpp#L61):

```
cv::Size getPreferencesCalibrationPatternSize(void *preferences);
```

> 'getPreferencesCalibrationPatternSize' has C-linkage specified, but returns user-defined type 'cv::Size' (aka 'Size_') which is incompatible with C

Any pointer to get a step further in this compilation process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Opened an issue on the repository: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration/issues/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation issue [was fixed](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration/commit/a4b0aa41afcb45b873bdd48a53e8a536ecbad64a) by removing the following lines around the error-generating usage of `cv::Size`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today. You need to make sure that your source code files, usually the '.c' and the '.h' files, are interpreted as C++ headers and sources. For this specific error, trace back which file calls `cv::Size` and change its type to C++ header/source.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Quang Hoang. Unfortunately in my case, the file reporting the error already has the Type "Default - C++ Header" in Xcode.